# ng-click with Bootstrap Rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Rating component and I have to use on-leave method to call my javascript function. Except in IE all the other browsers execute on-leave function on click event also. But in IE, till I leave the stars'div the function is not called. I can not even use ng-click as it is not supported by Bootstrap Rating component (My angular version is 1.1.5)

```
<div id="ratingDiv{{$index}}" style="display:none;" class="ratingDivClass">
<span class="ratingPoorClass">Poor</span>
<rating id="rateStars" onclick="$jq('#loader').show();" value="userRating" max="5" 
on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" 
on-leave="saveRating(message.id,userRating,$index,message.entity);"></rating>
<span class="ratingGoodClass">Very Good</span>
</div>
```

**Problem:** In IE, till I leave the div the function is not called

**Tried:**

1. Calling function on on-click and not on-leave: It does not pass scope related parameters
2. Trigger mouseleave() method on on-click of the div: Did not work :(

Please let me know if anyone has any solution for this.

Comment: do you use AngularJS? because this looks like mixture of angular, standard JS and jquery. angular has its own [ngMouseleave directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave)

Comment: Ya i use angular JS...but ngMouseleave will not help me as I want an on-click function. I want to trigger the function call on click event of the Rating component

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem with angularjs and IE. In my case the key-down did not work and the the solutions was to use the key-up event (see http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

In your case you may be having this issue  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1277

I am not familiar with 'on-leave' above, but you could try the jquery blur method instead: https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

Based on docs of [ng-mouseleave](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave), you can try the below code.

On my last project i used below code for IE8 to support some functions..
You could try on-leave also.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
    document.createElement('ng-include');
    document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
    document.createElement('ng-view');   
    document.createElement('alert');
    document.createElement('progress');
    document.createElement('ng-mouseleave');// try this

    // Optionally these for CSS
    document.createElement('ng:include');
    document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
    document.createElement('ng:view');
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks all!! I tried the above solutions but somehow was not able achieve what was needed. So I have made the last work around I had in my mind. Having an on-click function on entire html and verify if the rating component is clicked and then execute my code. I hope bootstrap would support on-click too in future versions!